# Running Python code with selenium outputs a strange error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

In the following code, I'm using Python and importing Selenium to scrape a website. However, every time I run the code, this strange error pops up. I'm using the latest Chrome browser version, the latest Chrome webdriver version, and the latest Selenium Python versions.

I had a friend run the exact same code with the exact same versions of Chrome and Python and webdriver and Selenium, and it worked perfectly fine.

Why is this happening?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

urls = [

    'https://wuzzuf.net/jobs/p/FeluBSsQtYBB-Quality-Control-Inspector-Breadfast-Cairo-Egypt' 
        
        ]
PATH = Service("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")

for url in urls:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=PATH)
    driver.get(url)

pre=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div/main/section[2]/div[4]/span[2]').text
print(pre)
```

Output:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49782/devtools/browser/683c8f33-aec7-45ce-aba0-78efb1458ee1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\AUC\Downloads\Projects\crawlers\get_details.py", line 16, in <module>
    pre=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div/main/section[2]/div[4]/span[2]').text
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AUC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 738, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AUC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 344, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\AUC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response     
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="app"]/div/main/section[2]/div[4]/span[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=118.0.5993.118); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF667338EF2+54786]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6672A5612]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF66715A64B]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF66719B79C]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF66719B91C]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6671D6D87]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6671BBEAF]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6671D4D02]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6671BBC43]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF667190941]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF667191B84]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF667687F52+3524194]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6676DD800+3874576]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6676D5D7F+3843215]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6673D5086+694166]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6672B0A88]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6672ACA94]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6672ACBC2]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF66729CC83]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFA6F1A257D+29]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFA7030AA78+40]
```

I tried updating everything to the latest versions.

Comment: What element you are trying to search in the webpage? Can you share the element name? we can always try to find element by class, by id, by tag as well

Comment: I'm trying to fetch the value (or text) in front of salary on the website link provided. In this case, the value is supposed to be the text "Confidential"

Comment: The link is just redirecting to the Home page. It seems like that job is removed

Answer (score 0):

You don't wait for that element to be visible and your selector seemed to be incorrect.

Unfortunately, this site has autogenerated selector, so you should search for salary element by containing text `Salary` and get inner span that doesn't contain `Salary`.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://wuzzuf.net/jobs/p/FeluBSsQtYBB-Quality-Control-Inspector-Breadfast-Cairo-Egypt')


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
salary = wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//section//*[contains(.,'Salary')]//span[not(contains(.,'Salary'))]")))
print(salary.text)
```